# jQuery Stickem not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have the jQuery Stickem plugin activated on a client website. It is working well in Firefox and Safari yet is failing to activate in Chrome. I can't figure out why it is not firing?

http://applied-analytix.com/solutions/applied-analytix-modular-planning-system/

Left column should stick.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is erroring out where you're calling a .imagesLoaded function which I am presuming is from https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded. However, I do not see this file included in your js.

```
$('#page').imagesLoaded( function() {
        $(".layout").stickem({
            start: 109
        });
    });
```